# Batch rename file by removing first 6 characters and adding it behind the filename

Tags: finder, automator

is there any way to rename a file automatically by Automator, removing first 6 characters and moving them to the back of the file name (and adding a space before that)?

Example
20-10-03 Testing.zip

Rename to:
Testing 20-10-03.zip

Thanks!

Comment: When comparing the example filename to the title and body of your question, it is not consistent. While you are saying to remove the first 6 characters from the front of the filename, the example clearly shows you removing the first 9 characters and my answer conforms to the example filename.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one of the ways it can be done in **Automator** is by using a **Run Shell Script** *action* with the *example* **bash script** *code* shown further below.

You can create an **Automator** *Workflow*, or *Service/Quick Action*, workflow.

If you do just a **Workflow**, then you will need to add a **Files & Folders** *action*, e.g. **Get Selected Finder Items** or **Get Specified Finder Items**, and then add a **Run Shell Script** *action*.

If you do a **Service/Quick Action**, then you only need a **Run Shell Script** *action*.

If you do choose a **Service/Quick Action** then set it to use **files and folders** in **Finder**.

For the **Run Shell Script** *action*, have its *settings* configured as:

- Shell: `/bin/bash`
- Pass input: **as arguments**
- Replace the *default code* of the **Run Shell Script** *action* with the *example* **bash script** *code*.

The *example* **bash script** *code* uses [**shell parameter expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to slice and dice the *fully qualified pathname* of the file(s) passed to it into the necessary pieces and then *renames* the file(s) using the `mv` *command* with the `-n` *option*, which will not overwrite an existing file, based on the *values* of the sliced and diced pieces of the *fully qualified pathname*.

As *coded*, it uses a [**regex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to only act on *files* that *starts* with *two digits*, followed by a *dash*, followed by *two digits*, followed by a *dash*, followed by *two digits*, followed by a *space*, followed by *additional characters* and a *file extension*, e.g.: **20-10-03 Testing.zip**

*Example* **bash script** *code*:

```bash
    # f = fully qualified pathname
    # d = directory pathname
    # fn = filename with extension
    # n = filename without extension
    # e = filename extension
    # p = filename prefix e.g. '20-10-03'
    # s = filename suffix (filename without prefix, space, and extension)


for f in "$@"
do
    [ -f "${f}" ] || continue
    d="${f%/*}"
    fn="${f##*/}"
    [[ ${fn} =~ ^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[[:space:]].*\..* ]] || continue
    n="${fn%.*}"
    e="${fn##*.}"
    p="${n%${n#????????}}"
    s="${n:9}"
    [ -n "${s}" ] || continue
    mv -n "${f}" "${d}/${s} ${p}.${e}"
done
```

The output of which would be, e.g.: **Testing 20-10-03.zip**

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **bash script** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>

Comment: Works beautifully and perfectly clear explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @Valen Sinclair, Appreciate the thanks. Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) If you feel it's appropriate, I'd appreciate you marking my answer as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86884/automator-how-to-replace-a-particular-string-with-the-filename) might be what you're looking for. You need regex, or a shell script using regex working with Automator.